# Cannot install rdme

Tags: npm

I cannot install `rdme`. I have correctly installed Node.js:

```
grafeno30@linux:~$ npm -v
8.11.0
grafeno30@linux:~$ node -v
v16.16.0
```

and when I execute `npm install rdme` I get the the following message:

```
up to date, audited 377 packages in 888ms
82 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
5 moderate severity vulnerabilities
To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I execute the following command: `npm audit fix --force`

If I execute `rdme` on the screen appears "command not found".

Comment: You _can_ install rdme, and have done. But it's not installed _globally_; run it via npx or scripts or just node_modules/.bin/ (assuming you haven't broken anything with the --force).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Navigate to your "node modules" folder in nodejs and try running

`npm i rdme@version` 
eg- `npm i rdme@8.0.0-beta.2`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you #jonrsharpe

I have been able to run it with npx.

I have able to execute with npx.

I didn't read all the documentation:

**Once installed in your project, we recommend using npx (which is included if you have npm installed) to prefix all of your CLI commands. For example:
npx rdme validate [file]***